# How to use the facebook SDK in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I'm trying to use the facebook sdk to show a share dialog in my app.
When I have the app installed in the divice its ok.
The problem is when I don't have the app instaled and I try to use the
FeedDialog.
This is the code:

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {              
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this, Session.getActiveSession(), params)).setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                    if(error != null){
                        Toast.makeToast(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                      
                }

            })
            .build();
        feedDialog.show();
}
```

The error that appears is: "com.facebook.FacebookException: Attempted to use a Session that was not open."

I got this example on the facebook page, whats wrong wit it?

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook documentation :

> Session is used to authenticate a user and manage the user's session
>   with Facebook.
>
> Sessions must be opened before they can be used to make a Request.
>   When a Session is created, it attempts to initialize itself from a
>   TokenCachingStrategy. Closing the session can optionally clear this
>   cache. The Session lifecycle uses SessionState to indicate its state.
>   Once a Session has been closed, it can't be re-opened; a new Session
>   must be created.

Try to open Session.getActiveSession() in oncreate method.
then in the in the body try put request

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

              // callback when session changes state
              @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                 Bundle params = new Bundle();
             params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
                 params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
                  params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
                 params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
                 params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this, Session.getActiveSession(), params)).setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                    if(error != null){
                        Toast.makeToast(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                      
                }

            })
            .build();
        feedDialog.show();
                     }
```